# Vim forbid to modify an option

Tags: vim

How I can set an option and forbid to change its value anywhere else?

For example, I use 2 spaces per tab: `set shiftwidth=2`.

And vim runtime change it for some file types. I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
augroup Forbid
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType * set shiftwidth=2
augroup END
```

Normally, you'd use `setlocal` instead of `set` but you want the same value for every filetype so... `set` will do.